# How to create a dataimport handler in Solr cloud?

Tags: solr, solr4

I have 3 instances of Solr 6.6.3 and a single zookeeper instance. 
And I have to configure a dataimport handler to get data from Cassandra cluster.
Please help me.
Thanks In Advance

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at [Cassandra and Solr Integration using JDBC and Apache Thrift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47878583/cassandra-and-solr-integration-using-jdbc-org-apache-thrift-transport-ttranspor)? What about [Solandra](https://github.com/tjake/Solandra)?

Comment: It was an issue with Zookeeper 3.3.6 , as it was not compatible with Solr 6.x  ... Now I am using zookeeper 3.4.x and It is working  ... Thanks for your suggestion